# Why does user see only see certain groups when Site Collection Admin?

Tags: permissions, groups

I have a user that is checking permissions for a site, and she cannot see certain groups.

The groups that she is attempting to view members of are owned by group that she is a member of. (I just set that ownership relationship up on all those groups.) She can see some, but not all of the groups that she should have rights to see.

When I add her as a Site Collection Administrator, then she see all the groups (of course).

What could be causing her not to be able to see some of the groups?

Answer (score 2):

when creating a group in sharepoint, there is an option for specifying whether or not outside users can see the membership of the group. My guess is that even if she is a member of the owning group, she can't see the group(s) membership because she is not the direct group owner and the option to not show members is selected.

Try editing the group and allowing membership to be visible.

Comment: If that works, what would my next step be? I do not want to give everyone access to view the group members.